# Passport.js: How does LocalStrategy accesses the user information?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js

I have read several articles explaining how the passport authentication flows and understood most of the concepts. However, there are still a couple of vague points to be explained so that I can wrap my head around Passport once and for all.
Let's see this simple example that implements **user registration**:

> passport.js

```
passport.use(
  'register',
  new LocalStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: 'username',
      passwordField: 'password',
      passReqToCallback: true,
      session: false,
    },
    (req, username, password, done) => {
      // TODO:Why is req.body.email is used and not req.body.username
      // And how are these values passed to register in the first place?
      console.log(username);
      console.log(req.body.email);

      try {
        User.findOne({
          where: {
            [Op.or]: [
              {
                username,
              },
              { email: req.body.email },
            ],
          },
        }).then(user => {
          if (user != null) {
            console.log('username or email already taken');
            return done(null, false, {
              message: 'username or email already taken',
            });
          }
          /**
           * on register the user’s password is hashed and salted with the encryption package bcrypt
           * 
           */
          bcrypt.hash(password, BCRYPT_SALT_ROUNDS).then(hashedPassword => {
            User.create({
              username,
              password: hashedPassword,
              email: req.body.email,
            }).then(user => {
              console.log('user created');
              return done(null, user);
            });
          });
        });
      } catch (err) {
        //In case of an Error interacting with our database, we need to invoke done(err)
        //Calling done will make the flow jump back into passport.authenticate. 
        //It's passed the error, user and additional info object (if defined).
        return done(err);
      }
    },
  ),
);
```

> registerUser.js:

```
app.post('/registerUser', (req, res, next) => {
    //Calling done will make the flow jump back into passport.authenticate. 
    //It's passed the error, user and additional info object (if defined).

    passport.authenticate('register', (err, user, info) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
      if (info !== undefined) {
        console.error(info.message);
        res.status(403).send(info.message);
      } else {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
        req.logIn(user, error => {
          console.log(user);
          const data = {
            first_name: req.body.first_name,
            last_name: req.body.last_name,
            email: req.body.email,
            username: user.username,
          };
          console.log(data);
          User.findOne({
            where: {
              username: data.username,
            },
          }).then(user => {
            console.log(user);
            user
              .update({
                first_name: data.first_name,
                last_name: data.last_name,
                email: data.email,
              })
              .then(() => {
                console.log('user created in db');
                res.status(200).send({ message: 'user created' });
              });
          });
        });
      }
    })(req, res, next);
  });
```

**Question 1:** I do not see how the code inside **LocalStrategy** has access to the user information knowing that **Passport.authenticate** has been called in this manner:

```
    app.post('/registerUser', (req, res, next) => {
passport.authenticate('register', (err, user, info) => {
```

So how does the code inside **regiser LocalStrategy ** accesses the username,email and password:

```
(req, username, password, done) => {
  console.log(username);
  console.log(req.body.email);
```

**Question2:** How come **username** inside **LocalStrategy** is called **username**  directly (the same thing for password) and email is called by **req.body.email**?

```
 console.log(username);
  console.log(req.body.email);
```

and here:

```
User.create({
              username,
              password: hashedPassword,
              email: req.body.email,
            })
```

**Question 3:** Why is there a need to update the user information in the **request callback** if the user has already been created in the **register LocalStrategy**:

> registerUser.js

```
  .update({
                first_name: data.first_name,
                last_name: data.last_name,
                email: data.email,
              })
```

> passport.js

```
User.create({
              username,
              password: hashedPassword,
              email: req.body.email,
            })
```

**EDIT 1**
**Question 4:**  What is the role of **(req, res, next);** at the end of the **POST** callback?

Comment: useful articles I found: [Johnny Situ](https://medium.com/@johnnysitu/node-js-user-authentication-with-passport-local-strategy-37605fd99715), [Toon.io](http://toon.io/understanding-passportjs-authentication-flow)

Answer (score 0):

For question 1: when you are calling `passport.authenticate('register')` you should pass `req`, `res`, and next at then end, so that `passport.use(localStrategy)` gets the user information.

For question 2, username getting from the `req` object inside `localstrategy`

For question 3: You don't need to update the user info.instead you can directly send the res to user in `.then()` function as you did:

```
then(() => {
  console.log('user created in db');
  res.status(200).send({
    message: 'user created'
  });
});
```

Comment: So (req, res, next) at the end of the POST request is passing those arguments to the register code inside passport.js? If so, I don't see how the syntax makes that work. Is there something I should learn or relearn about the syntax of the POST request?

Comment: So (req, res, next) at the end of the POST request is passing those arguments to the register code inside passport.js? 

YES

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1&2:** The answer lies within the object that is passed **LocalStrategy**:

```
   {
      usernameField: 'username',
      passwordField: 'password',
      passReqToCallback: true,
      session: false,
    }
```

The attribute **passReqToCallback**, the **req** will be passed as the first argument to the verify callback:

```
(req, username, password, done) => {}
```

However, what is still not clear is how the username and password are passed to this function. Why are they defined in this manner in this object:

```
 usernameField: 'username',
 passwordField: 'password',
```

Shouldn't they be accessed through req.body.username just like the email:

```
User.findOne({
          where: {
            [Op.or]: [
              {
                username,
              },
              { email: req.body.email },
            ],
          },
```

**Question 3:** Here's an explanation I found:

> I could have passed this extra data through to the middleware as well,
>   but I want Passport to only handle authentication, not user creation
>   as well. Modularization, remember.
>
> Plus, if the authentication were to be split out into a separate
>   service with a separate database of just encrypted usernames and
>   passwords, this would make it easier to do so, then use the username
>   or ID to find and update the corresponding user record in this
>   registration service.